# Chemfig: How make a rotation around one bond in one molecule?

Tags: arrows, rotating, chemfig

I was looking for a way to indicate the point in a molecule where a rotation around a bond would occur. I found some, but I didn't know if they would work on CHEMFIG.

Comment: If you have already a solution to your problem, ask without including the solution and reply yourself making a separate answer in order to not list it as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2):

So I had an inspiration, and I created a way to do this in CHEMFIG, and it's easy, you don't need to create new commands.

Just create a brand on a bond, and use that brand as the starting and ending point of a arrow. An adjustment in the exit and arrival angles of the arrow creates the desired circular shape.

No new packages, no new commands, no new tools

%=========================================================

```
\documentclass[margin={12mm 12mm}]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\setatomsep{1.8em}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}

\schemestart

\chemfig{A-[@a0,3]B}

\qquad

\chemfig{A-[@b1,3]B}

\qquad

\chemfig{A-[@c2,3]B}

\chemmove{\draw[red, shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt](a).. controls +(80:16mm) and +(280:16mm)..(a);

    \draw[red,shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt](b).. controls +(130:16mm) and +(330:16mm)..(b);

    \draw[red,shorten <=4pt,shorten >=4pt](c).. controls +(170:14mm) and +(10:14mm)..(c);
}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

%================================================
[image]